# Plotting multiple graphs in separate axes from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe I want to plot.

The dataframe has five columns, one being used as the x-axis, and the other four columns as the y-axis values.

The current code in use is :

```
ax = plt.gca()

df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='Gr', color = 'brown', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='R', color='red', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='B', color='blue', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='Gb', color='cyan', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

This outputs 4 graphs, all in the **same axes**. However, this makes the graphs not very readable, as the graphs can be very noisy and they overlap with each other a lot.

For example:

[image]

Is there a way to separate the four graphs into different axes so that I can read each graph separately, other than repeating the entire code four times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,8))

df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='Gr', color = 'brown', ax=ax[0,0])
df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='R', color='red', ax=ax[0,1])
df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='B', color='blue', ax=ax[1,0])
df.plot(kind='line',x='Vertical',y='Gb', color='cyan', ax=ax[1,1])

plt.show()
```

OR

```
df[['Gr','R','B','Gb']].plot(subplots=True, figsize=(10,8))
```